# SSIS passing flat file paths as command line parameters

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I have an ssis package that takes two flat files and a database tables as connections. I want to run the ssis package from command line by passing these 3 connections as command line parameters. How should I call?

After some google search I found that if we are using a DB as connection, this is how to pass. But couldn't figure out how to pass connection parameters for flat files.

```
DTExec.exe /F "<packagepath> /set \package.connections[MyDB].properties[ServerName];SS2K8SV01_Prod
```

Comment: Can you use a stored proc? That's how I've done it. Like so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017 (you also need to set the parameter as the source in the properties for the connection in the package)

Comment: Would you like to directly configure the Connection Manager or are you using SSIS Variables which then drive the ConnectionString property for your connection manager?

Comment: @billinkc : I would like to directly configure the connection manager and then pass the paths of files as command line parameters

Comment: @Jacob : No , cannot use a stored Proc in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume I have a flat file connection manager called FFCM and I'd like to update the ConnectionString property to C:\ssisdata\output\B.txt

```
dtexec.exe 
/file Package2.dtsx 
/set 
\Package.Connections[FFCM].Properties[ConnectionString];C:\ssisdata\input\B.txt
```

These are case sensitive values so the connection manager must be called FFCM. If there is a ffcm, this wouldn't work.

If you have to deal with spaces in the path, honestly, it's easier to rename the path than to deal with it but I believe the entire argument needs be in double quotes, not just the portion after the semicolon

```
dtexec.exe 
/file Package2.dtsx 
/set 
\Package.Connections[FFCM].Properties[ConnectionString];C:\ssisdata\input\B.txt
/set 
\Package.Connections[FFCM2].Properties[ConnectionString];C:\ssisdata\input\BC.txt
/set 
\Package.Connections[MyDB].Properties[ServerName];localhost
```

### How do I determine what the thing is after the /set

By default, F4 will bring up the Properties window for whatever you have clicked on in the SSIS editor. Look for the PackagePath property of a given object and that identifies the "base" path.

[image]

From there, you will need to access the Expressions collection to identify the property you'd like to set `ConnectionString`

[image]

Thus making the full path we will SET via command line as

```
\Package.Connections[FFCM].Properties[ConnectionString]
```